# Wrong output in java

Tags: java

I have written the program which takes integer and string inputs, and removes duplicate and print it if given number is armstrong, but my program is giving wrong output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Main {
    
    public static boolean checkArmstrong(int num) {
        int org=num, sum=0;
        while(num>0) {
            sum += (int)Math.pow((num%10), 3);
            num /= 10;
        }
        if(sum == org)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
    public static String removeDuplicate(String str) {
        char[] charr=str.toCharArray();
        char[] resarr=new char[charr.length];
        int[] max=new int[123];
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0; i<charr.length; i++) 
            if(max[(int)charr[i]++]==0)
                resarr[k++]=charr[i];
        String res=new String(resarr);
        return res;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int num=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        String str=sc.nextLine();
        if(checkArmstrong(num)) {
            String res=removeDuplicate(str);
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you would show us the input, the actual output, and the expected output. Are you trying to handicap the people who would help you?

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine only with 3 digit Amstrong numbers:

```
sum += (int) Math.pow((num % 10), 3);
```

You could avoid hardcoding this value by checking it at runtime:

```
public static boolean checkArmstrong(int num) {
    if (num == 0)
        return true; // also avoids log10(0) 
    
    int org = num, sum = 0;
    int digits = (int) (Math.log10(num) + 1);
    
    while (num > 0) { 
       sum += (int) Math.pow((num % 10), digits);
       num /= 10;
    }
   
    return sum == org;
}
```

Comment: @Deadbeef, even if I prefer Allman, you are right with the last redundant operation. You got it! ; )

Answer (score 1):

You created would have created an infinite loop

except that the number is an int... :(
For fun, let's imagine it were not.

```
while(num>0) {
        sum += (int)Math.pow((num%10), 3);
        num /= 10;
    }
```

num is asymptotic to 0. After infinite divisions it becomes 1/infinity, but never truly zero. Ask yourself the question, 'If Joey is 16 feet away from the wall, and every step covers half of the remaining distance to the wall, how many steps will it take to get him to the wall? Infinite steps. Joey will never get there. Just like your while loop would never end .

Thank you Deadbeef for a link to a [hilarious illustration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffUnNaQTfZE&feature=youtu.be) of this concept.

Comment: that's not true, when num become less than 10, num /= 10 would make num become 0

Comment: It would indeed end, when it reaches a value too close to 0. That would throw an `ArithmeticNumberException`, as num would be `NaN` But it's an int, not a floating point variable, so above comment is right

Comment: @aran that also not true, num is int type, so the result when dividing num by 10 will also be int and the remainder would be discarded. E.g: 9 / 10 = 0

Comment: @HưngChu I'm telling exactly that, in the second part: *But it's an int, not a floating point variable, so above comment is right.* My comment was to point out that even with a floating point number, the loop wouldn't be infinite. It would reach a point where it would be too close to 0, hence NaN

Comment: lol sorry i was missing the second part

Comment: Your last paragraph makes me think of [this video](https://youtu.be/ffUnNaQTfZE)

Comment: @Deadbeef that was HILARIOUS! Thank you for that

Comment: @ColeHenrich your statement would be true also for non-int variables....if floating point math wasn't broken. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number *(It would throw an Exception)*

Comment: @Aran Thank you for the info.

Comment: @ColeHenrich than you for your genuine way of reply. upvoting cause you deserve it